# How to specify correct output folder for CSS using SASS & LiveReload?

Tags: css, sass, livereload

Having a strange problem.

I'm using SASS, I have compass installed, but don't need to use it because I have LiveReload.

With LiveReload I've pasted the script into my index2.html file. Then in Output Paths I have my sass/main.scss folder targeted to the css/main.css folder. However for some reason it still outputs to a stylesheet folder.

This is driving me nuts, how do I force SASS or lifereload to make sure I'm outputting to the correct folder? I never created the stylesheets folder and when I deleted and make a change and save my main.scss file it recreates the stylesheets folder and puts main.css inside that X_X

**Edit:** I believe it is a config file somewhere in this python project. I Found a config.rb file, but path seems fine there, so it must be another setting somewhere... I'm going to keep looking, or I could ask the Python dev Monday

*config.rb*

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

require 'compass/util'

require 'compass/browser_support'

require 'compass/sass_extensions'

require 'compass/version'

require 'compass/errors'

require 'compass_twitter_bootstrap'

require 'breakpoint'

require 'toolkit'



# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:

http_path = "/"

css_dir = "css"

sass_dir = "sass"

images_dir = "img"

javascripts_dir = "scripts/js"

environment = :production

output_style = (environment == :production) ? :compressed : :expanded
```

[image]

Comment: Note, still no luck... but I did install the trail for Codekit and bam... it outputs to the css folder. Hopefully someone can help me with LiveReload however

Comment: I would suggest you go ALL IN and buy codekit. It does a whole lot more stuff than LiveReload that you will enjoy.

Comment: @nouveau I actually might do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was how it was setup by the previous developer, not that he was causing a bug, it was just the way he had it setup.

I created a new folder and moved my files there and now my SCSS files in the SASS folder does compile correctly into the CSS folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your link to your css with the appropriate styles folder you speak of. Wouldn't that be just as quick of a solution?

Comment: Well yeah I could, but I like my css inside of a css folder, not a stylesheets folder... this is such a strange bug

Comment: It seems to be a limitation of the tool you are using. Something is telling it to make that stylesheet folder - have you asked the people who make LiveReload?